# VMware Workstation 8 automation with Ruby/Rake?

Tags: ruby, rake, vmware, vmware-workstation

I'm looking into doing more automation in our build process; We use TeamCity and rake for our build tasks.  We build our website into an MSI, and that's the extent of our CI system.  I want to add deployment to the automation.

We use VMware Workstation so I want to add a build task to:

1. Revert a VM to a certain snapshot.
2. Install the MSI on the VM.
3. Run some acceptance tests on the live environment.

Does anyone have any advice on the best way to achieve this goal?

I've seen the following but not sure if they're suitable:

- [Vixr](https://github.com/rhythmx/vixr) seems like it might be usable through my rake tasks, but I am not sure as it's quite old and I don't know the compatibility with Workstation 8.
- [RVC](https://github.com/vmware/rvc) looks good but I don't think it's compatible with VM Workstation.

Comment: Thanks for that, vmrun seems like the ticket, add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple tasks, you should consider using `vmrun.exe` exists in every workstation installation folder.

Manual is here: [vmrun Documentation](http://vmware.com/pdf/vix160_vmrun_command.pdf)